# Joining multiple Django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have three Django models related by foreign key constraint and they all have data. How should I join all of them together and display the data in my template? (something similar to INNER JOIN in SQL).

The view is,

```
def seeAllData(request):
template = loader.get_template('seeAllData.html')
context = {
    'From1' : Form1(),
    'Form2' : Form2(),
    'Form3' : Form3(),
}

return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Also, when I try the above approach, I get some text fields in the form rather than the data. (I want to show the data in a grid format).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you load any data in your `Form1(..)`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [bind your forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound) to model instances if you want data to be loaded.

It could look like this (depends on how your models are structured, you did not show your models so I can only make something up):

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def see_all_data(request):
    m1 = get_object_or_404(Model1, pk=1)
    ctx = {
        'From1' : Form1(instance=m1),
        'Form2' : Form2(instance=m1.model2_instance),
        'Form3' : Form3(instance=m1.model3_instance),
    }
    return render(request, 'seeAllData.html', ctx)
```

NOTICE: using `instance=` argument assumes you are using `ModelForms`.